# post form data to api (axios) reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, formik

I am trying to send form data to a server with axios. As you can see I am using Formik.
So far I ve tried these codes:

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShosH.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0E7w.png)

[picture 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or1V3.png)

[picture 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bswHm.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried sent `Formular` with `axios.post` to your backend. Some info on [axios post requests](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example) and connecting [frontend to backend](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/).

In your second picture, it might be easier to send the data in the `onSubmit`.

```js
onSubmit: {(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
  console.log(values) // Just to be sure you have them correct

  // POST request
    axios.post('http:localhost:portNUM', values) // Add headers if you have any.
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    .finally(() => setSubmitting(false))
  }
}
```

It might also be easier to use a `useEffect` within the `onSubmit`, just to make life a bit easier. If you know how to use react hooks and if not, I would recommend learning them.

Comment: Thank you FLorent. I will try this code and send you my feedback.